# Erro Gradle em uma aplicação React native

Tags: react, react-native

Estou criando uma aplicação para estudo com React Native e apareceu esse erro abaixo. Alguém sabe como resolver? *Estou iniciando agora com React e React Native e não tenho ideia de como consertar*

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip'.
>   Build file 'c:\Users\Design\Pictures\arq\mapa\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\build.gradle' line: 20
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-maps'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Verifique as configurações de instalação para Android que aparecem neste link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: Olhei e conferi. Tá tudo certo. Agora surgiu outro erro também: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31310379/31490178-9cb0a3c6-af32-11e7-9a5b-cfb0ee44d8ee.png

Comment: Parece algo relacionado a exportação do seu componente. Veja se este link te ajuda https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332

Answer (score 0):

Em seu projeto adicione ao arquivo android/build.gradle esta linha de código **supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"**.

Exemplo:

`ext{
//...
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}`